# Cannot quickly move Tether out of the exchanges into my wallet compared to other pairs (why)?

Tags: client, exchanges, altcoin, trading

Getting my feet wet trading on a few exchanges (takes forever to get verified BTW) and have persistent problems over the past few months getting Tether out of the exchanges.

My wallet is fine, the Tether website does not show any issues, nothing stated on the exchanges, but I noticed I cannot quickly / readily move my Tether out of the exchanges compared to everything else.

Is there a different mechanism for getting Tether out of the exchanges since it is tied to "real" money at 1-to-1 ratio?

Are the exchanges somehow "sandbagging" the Tether and / or other coin until it is more beneficial for them to complete the transaction?

I know the last part of the question sounds conspiratorial, but look at the price behaviour on each of the Tether-sided paired instruments (USDT-BTC, USDT-anything)...
   Thanks in advance, 
                  Gette

Comment: Not an answer, but you are might want to read [this fine item on Bitfinex, BTC-e and Tether](https://medium.com/@bitfinexed/meet-spoofy-how-a-single-entity-dominates-the-price-of-bitcoin-39c711d28eb4). I'd get the hell out of Tether if I could and only use it for short swaps if ever required.

Comment: Your question lacks specifics. For example, is it taking 20 minutes, 4 hours, or 3 days?